# Conflicting notions of authorization when implementing an App with Oauth

Tags: web-applications, oauth, authorization, oauth-2.0, crud

This is mainly a wording issue. But albeit a very important one, which can cause possible misinterpretations in big code bases being maintained by even bigger teams. Let's say we have a very basic CRUD/RESTful app with an authentication system. In this case, the authenticated user trying to fulfill a data-changing request (POST/PUT) will be then identified by the server (authentication) and then it will be checked whether this identified user has the right to create/update the resource in question (**authorization**).

Now let's say I'll implement the Oauth protocol to at a later stage support some kind of web API solution. In this case, The user from Client App A will have to ask for **authorization** from the resource provider to do something.

So as of now, we have two valid notions of **authorization** inside the same app. At the application level it is not that big of a problem, since we can enclosed the two notions in a relevant namespace, but in the DB I have two valid candidates that **cannot** share the name **authorizations**.

As I'm not a big fan of namespacing table names, I'd like suggestions for possible renaming of one of them (or maybe some other wild solution you might have implemented).

Cheerio

Comment: Why wouldn't the OAuth authorization and the server authorization simply be a single DB table?

Comment: The OAuth authorization grants an external user from an external application authorization to do whatever on a resource from the resource owner in the main application. The server authorization grants a user from the main app authorization to do whatever on a resource in the map app as well.

Comment: The Oauth authorization has therefore a coupling with the client application it refers to besides handling all the Oauth protocol stuff. The "simple" authorization is just a filtering for certain actions on the main app (like checking whether a user has authorization to edit a resource). Having them together in the same table would be a bit overkill, since the "simple" authorization does not need a lot of what the Oauth authorization demands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `oauthgrants` or just prefix `authorizations` with more descriptive names?:
`user_authorizations`
and `app_user_authorizations`.  This might violate your rule about namespacing, but would be much more descriptive.

`user_authorizations` or `authorizations` would just have what the user is allows to do within the system.

`app_user_authorizations` or `oauthgrants` would have which privileges the user has granted to third party applications via OAuth.  It would store: user ID, OAuth 2.0 client ID, scope granted, refresh token (if exists), expiration (if exists).  It may also have the access tokens depending on how you implement them (or they may be in another table or not stored because they're cryptographically verifiable)

Comment: I like the word "grant". I think it is exactly what I needed for the issue. Needless to say, as you stated, the prefixes are exactly what I want to avoid. So I'll stick to "authorizations" for the app and "grants" for the oauth workflow, they seem good enough independent concepts. Nothing like asking an english native speaker about the exact meaning of words :)